# Returning data from firebase functions returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this code

```
exports.battle = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(context.auth){
        var difficulty = randInt(2,10) / 10
        var user = context.auth["uid"]
        
        var userHP
        var userLevel
        var userDmg 
        var resultUserDmg = []
        var resultUserHp = []

        var monsterHP
        var monsterLevel
        var monsterDmg
        var resultMonsterDmg = []
        var resultMonsterHp = []

        

        var ref = db.ref(`players/${user}`);
        ref.child("hp").once("value", (snapshot) => {
           userHP = snapshot.val()
           monsterHP = userHP * difficulty

           ref.child("level").once("value", (snapshot) => {
                userLevel = snapshot.val()
                monsterLevel = userLevel * difficulty

                console.log("type"+typeof(userHP))
                console.log("value"+userHP)
                

                console.log("type"+typeof(monsterHP))
                console.log("value"+monsterHP)
                console.log("diff "+difficulty)


                while (userHP > 0 && monsterHP > 0){
                    userDmg = randInt(7, 14) * userLevel
                    monsterDmg = randInt(7, 14) * userLevel * difficulty


                    userHP = Math.round((userHP - monsterDmg)*10) /10;
                    console.log("userHP"+(userHP))
                    console.log("monsterDmg"+monsterDmg)
                    resultMonsterDmg.push(Math.round(monsterDmg*10) /10)
                    resultUserHp.push(Math.round(userHP*10)/10)
                    monsterHP = Math.round((monsterHP - userDmg)*10) /10;
                    console.log("userDmg"+userDmg)
                    console.log("monsterHP"+monsterHP)
                    resultUserDmg.push(Math.round(userDmg*10)/10)
                    resultMonsterHp.push(Math.round(monsterHP*10)/10)
                    console.log("----------")
                }

            
                var ref = db.ref(`players/${user}/coins`);
                ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                    var coinsNow = parseInt(snapshot.val());
                    const userRef = db.ref(`players/${user}`);
                    userRef.update({
                        'coins' : coinsNow+1
                    })
                });

                var result ={
                    userDmg : resultUserDmg,
                    userHp : resultUserHp,
                    monsterDmg : resultMonsterDmg,
                    monsterHp : resultMonsterHp,
                    monsterLvl : monsterLevel,
                };
                console.log("result is "+resultUserDmg)
                console.log("result is "+resultUserHp)
                console.log("result is "+resultMonsterDmg)
                console.log("result is "+resultMonsterHp)
                console.log("result is "+monsterLevel)
                return result 

            })
        })
    }
    else{
        console.log("User is not logged")
    }

    
})
```

Simply what this code does is that it calculates the player's life and damage against the monster using a while loop. This works correctly. The problem is when I want to send the data in the result variable to the user for further work. It returns null every time.
Do you know where the error is? The only thing I can think of is that the error would be in the return. Maybe it gets called before the requested data has any value. I don't know. I can't figure it out.

But I am sure that the values I want to send to the user are not null but have the values they should have. Here is the log from the firebase console

[Firebase console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXLnz.png)

Here is code that i am useing for client returning.
I always get null here

```
var battle = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('battle')
    battle().then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

**UPDATE:**
Frank's response was great direction. But I don't think it's entirely clear. After a longer search, I found a more understandable solution for me here: https://medium.com/@stephane.giron/firebase-cloud-functions-oncall-returned-before-end-of-the-function-2d898d8ff259

I simply changed this at the beginning of the code ann add this to the end

```
exports.battle = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(context.auth){
         return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                
                 /* 
                   . . . .                       
                     code 
                   . . . .
                            */

                 reslove(result)
)}
```

I hope this has helped someone else. I recommend adding `.catch` to the end of the code for possible errores but I'm not entirely sure so I don't want to possibly confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results from Promises bubble up to the caller, but only if you actually return them from within your `then` or `catch` callbacks. So inside every `once` callback you'll need to ensure that you `return` the value to the caller.

So first up, you're missing a top-level `return` statement in your top-level Cloud Function, which means that your `return result` never makes it to the caller.

So:

```
return ref.child("hp").once("value", (snapshot) => {
  ...
})
```

Next up, you'll need to do the same for `ref.child("level").once("value", (snapshot) => {` and other individual `once` calls.

Finally, if you have a loop where you perform an asynchronous operation (such as `once` or `update`) for each item in the loop, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for all of these operations to complete before completing the operation and return a value to the caller.

I recommend reading up on Promises here in [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) on MDN, in the Firebase documentation on [terminating functions: sync, async and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and by watching Doug's excellent video series linked there.

---

Unrelated, but this code is much more complex than needed:

```
var ref = db.ref(`players/${user}/coins`);
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var coinsNow = parseInt(snapshot.val());
    const userRef = db.ref(`players/${user}`);
    userRef.update({
        'coins' : coinsNow+1
    })
});
```

The Firebase Realtime Database nowadays has a built-in [`increment` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments), which means that you can simplify this to:

```
db.ref(`players/${user}/coins`).set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
```

Comment: Just to your simplification of my adding coins to players. It didn't work :D. I got this error in the firebase console. `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`

Comment: Did you look at the link for the documentation for that, and see how it applies to your case? --- Also did the rest of the answer make sense?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking wrong, but I can't find it in the documentation. But I've already found the bug. I have the `db` defined like this `const db = admin.database();`. So I can't use `firebase.database` but `admin.database`. So the code that works looks like this `db.ref(`players/${user}/coins`).set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1))`.